# How to Connect & get Data from GLONASS(Global Navigation Satellite System) to Android device

Tags: android, android-intent, android-ndk

I need to Connect & get Data from GLONASS(Global Navigation Satellite System) to Android device.
The Interface to communicate with the GLONASS is via USB.

Have Any Ideas in your mind ? please share them.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Android device and the GLONASS device. I suppose it is an USB client. So your Android device would have to be one with USB host mode enabled.